# how to configure vs code for cobol

Tags: visual-studio-code, cobol

thanks in advance for ur help.
Im learning cobol, but i have so many problems with the formatting and error hilighting, im using `BroadcomMFD.cobol-language-support` extension, but always says that my variables aren't inicialized and dont accept the `>>SOURCE FORMAT FREE`

Ive tried with other extensions and seeking extension configuration, but i dont know so good what should I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[broadcomMFD.cobol-language-support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=broadcomMFD.cobol-language-support) for Visual Studio Code, under Compatibility,

> The COBOL Language Support extension only supports IBM Enterprise COBOL. Other versions of COBOL are not supported.

[IBM Enterprise COBOL for z/OS 6.4](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/enterprise-cobol-zos-documentation-library), Language Reference (PDF download), Reference format, does not show any support for `>>SOURCE FORMAT FREE`.

I suggest getting the IBM Enterprise COBOL manual and formatting your programs according to the required reference format.

Comment: Right, thanks for sharing with me, but i still having the problem of "not inicialized variables", how can i deal with that?
The compiler run the code with no problems.

Comment: @Hen - It may simply be a warning, rather than an error. Please edit the question to include a small program that gives the error and the text of the message. If it is a warning, adding `VALUE` clauses may be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For an extension that will work with bold "modern" and "common" COBOL and isn't dialect specific you may want to use [`bitlang.gnucobol`](https://github.com/spgennard/vscode_cobol4gnucobol).

Find more features in [`rechinformatica.rech-editor-cobol`](https://github.com/RechInformatica/rech-editor-cobol), which is mostly focused on modern COBOL (its README notes that fixed-form reference format will have issues).

For an extension that supports multiple OpenText (previously MicroFocus) dialects and with more features, you can go with [`bitlang.cobol`](https://github.com/spgennard/vscode_cobol) (that complains about any other extension that has "cobol" somewhere).
An extension that may be used both alone and together with that is [`Micro-Focus-AMC.mfcobol`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Micro-Focus-AMC.mfcobol), but that's primarily useful if you have a recent version of its product installed.